# Zeta function for Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I read somewhere that there exists a zeta function for Gaussian integers that involves a combination of the Riemann zeta function and the Dirichlet beta function. Unfortunately, I have lost my source and and searching on internet on this subject does not yield the desired results. Can anyone give me such a definition for Gaussian integers, and possibly some articles I can read on the subject?

Comment: See p.6 of https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/personal/cw/download/fnt_chap5.pdf , and look up the Dirichlet $L$-function, which actually simplifies into another zeta in this case.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348599/l-function-easiest-way-to-see-the-following-sum?) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900768/is-there-a-closed-form-for-the-sum-of-the-reciprocal-cubes-of-all-coordinate-dis) threads (and links) which may help too,

Comment: For any number field there is a certain Dirichlet series called a Dedekind Zeta Function.  The Dedekind Zeta function for $\Bbb{Q}[i]$ "factors" as the Riemann Zeta function and Dirichlet Beta function.

Comment: Or [thisone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370893/dedekind-zeta-function-of-mathbbqi/2370928#2370928) and see a course on the [splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions) of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.